Magnetostatics - Coax w/ 2 Conductors
Why is the current enclosed is calculated in such a way that the ratio of the Area Enclosed to the Total Area is subtracted from one? Is this because the direction of the field is negative phi, and the subtraction from one allows us to express the field in a positive phi direction?


Yes, thank you! I never thought about it like that.

Please cite the source of any material you have obtained from elsewhere.

@Raquel  Citing material sourced from elsewhere is a site requirement. Please ad reference so that we are not obliged to delete your post.
